# How does one control the position of <h:messages> in JSF?

Tags: jsf-2

I have run out of ideas on this issue and would appreciate some help if possible:

I have the following in my xhtml page:

```
<h:panelGroup id="globalMesgArea" styleClass="globalMesgArea" layout="block">              
  <h:panelGrid columns="1">
    <h:messages for="globalMesgArea" layout="table" globalOnly="true" infoClass="infMsgs" errorClass="errMsgs"/>
  </h:panelGrid>
</h:panelGroup>
```

I can position the message content via the definition of the globalMesgArea StyleClass:

```
#globalMesgArea {
overflow: auto;
width:800px;
height:50px;
position:absolute;
bottom: 1em;
left:95px;
```

}

But (there is always a but...) if there is a page navigation specification error in my faces-config.xml then the error message appears further down the page as a `<ul>` instead of `<table>`.  Also, if I don't specify the "for" attribute in h:messages then the error doesn't "appear" but can be seen in the same (wrong) place in page view source.  All I can say is...."arrgghh!" :-)

The HTML snippet from page view source is:

```
<ul id="javax_faces_developmentstage_messages" title="Project Stage[Development]: Unhandled Messages"><li style="Color: orange">    Unable to find matching navigation case with from-view-id '/pageSource/myPage.xhtml' for action '/myPage.xhtml' with outcome '/myPage.xhtml' </li></ul></body>
```

Comment: May be because the project-stage is set to Development stage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have defined your `messages` tag with both the `for` and `globalOnly` attributes. According to the [Facelets documentation for the `messages` tag](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/messages.html), these attributes are mutually exclusive - if you specify a value for the `for` attribute, then global messages (with no client identifier) will not be displayed within the body of the rendered tag. According to the documentation, when you specify values for both, the `for` attribute takes precedence. The page navigation specification error does not have any client identifier associated with it. This would explain the behavior stated in your question:

> Also, if I don't specify the "for" attribute in h:messages then the error doesn't "appear" but can be seen in the same (wrong) place in page view source.

Additionally, when your project stage is set to Development instead of Production in your `web.xml`, any messages within the FacesContext that are not already displayed by an existing `messages` tag, will be displayed by a different `messages` tag (with id "javax_faces_developmentstage_messages" in Mojarra). Furthermore, this `messages` tag is always created in Development mode (even if there are no messages to display), as the `MessagesRenderer` is written to always emit such a tag in the Render-Response phase.

All `messages` tags are rendered as unordered lists `<ul>` in HTML. It is the `panelgrid` tag in your page that creates HTML tables (`table`) in the rendered response. This explains your comment:

> if there is a page navigation specification error in my faces-config.xml then the error message appears further down the page as a `<ul>` instead of `<table>`

If you want to correct this behavior, you could do either:

- Set the project stage to `Production` instead of `Development`. All unhandled messages would now appear in the Server logs. Mojarra will no longer render a `messages` tag with id `javax_faces_developmentstage_messages` in the response, when it operates in Production mode; instead, it will write messages (with the clientId, severity, summary and detail values of the message) to the logs.
- If you do not want to have unhandled messages to appear in the logs, which is undesirable when you are still developing the site, then you can have a `messages` tag in your page, with the `globalOnly` attribute set to `true`; all messages like your page navigation specification error will now appear in this `messages` tag. You can style this tag separately. There are pros and cons to this approach:

  - All errors arising out of development (like missing navigation specifications) will now appear in your page, unless you change the project stage to Production. The `messages` tag is therefore redundant if it does not display anything else.
  - You can display global messages that do not belong to any component in your pages, consistently. Also, you can style the `messages` tag and the contents using the `style`/`styleClass`, `infoStyle`/`infoClass`, `warnStyle`/`warnClass`, `errorStyle`/`errorClass` and ``` fatalStyle``fatalClass ``` attributes.

Also, you should consider using the `style`/`styleClass` attributes of the `messages` tag to style your messages, instead of relying on the parent elements' styles (which may vary from one containing element to another).

Comment: <div id="globalMesgArea" class="globalMesgArea"><table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><table><tr><td> Unable to find matching navigation case with from-view-id '/pageSource/myPage.xhtml' for action '/myPage.xhtml' with outcome '/myPage.xhtml' </td></tr></table></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

Comment: Hi and thanks for a full explanation of the mechanism involved in displaying messages.  I have tried removing the 'for' attribute and left just the globalOnly attribute set to 'true'.  However this time the error is produced in a <table> as I would expect but isn't visible.  I'm just wondering if it is something that I have got wrong in the background/foreground colours......anyway the HTML that is generated is shown in the above snippet:

Comment: Yep, fixed now after I added the style Class attribute values all the other message types:         <h:panelGroup id="globalMesgArea" styleClass="globalMesgArea" layout="block">              
          <h:panelGrid columns="1">
            <h:messages layout="table" globalOnly="true" 
                        infoClass="infMsgs"
                        warnClass="errMsgs"
                        errorClass="errMsgs"
                        fatalClass="errMsgs"/>            
          </h:panelGrid>
        </h:panelGroup>